# Change dropdown selection value based on another dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdowns `option1` and `option2`. I'm trying to Change dropdown selection based on another dropdown selection by index.

If first option is selected in `option1` the same has to be selected from `option2` dropdown also.

Eg: `option1 - mark . option2 - 20`

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/thorstorm1102/1mph3gow/2/)

```
    Option1<br>
    <select id="option1">
    <option value="john">john</option>
        <option value="mark">mark</option>
            <option value="rob">rob</option>
    </select><br>


    Option2<br>
        <select id="option2">
            <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Google "cascading dropdowns"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick for you.

```js
let option1 = document.getElementById('option1');
let option2 = document.getElementById('option2');

function matchOptions(e) {
 let option = e.target.selectedIndex;
 option1.selectedIndex = option;
 option2.selectedIndex = option;
}

option1.addEventListener('change', matchOptions);
option2.addEventListener('change', matchOptions);
```

```html
    Option1<br>
    <select id="option1">
    <option value="john">john</option>
        <option value="mark">mark</option>
            <option value="rob">rob</option>
    </select><br>


    Option2<br>
        <select id="option2">
            <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it done this way with pure JS

```
<head>
<title>My Func</title>
</head>
<body>
Option1<br>
<select id="option1" onchange="myFunction()">
  <option value="john">john</option>
    <option value="mark">mark</option>
        <option value="rob">rob</option>
</select><br>


Option2<br>
    <select id="option2">
        <option value="19">19</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="21">21</option>
    </select>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("option1");
  var y = document.getElementById("option2");
  if (x.value==='john'){
    y.value = 19;
  }else if(x.value==='mark'){
    y.value = 20;
  }else if(x.value==='rob'){
    y.value = 21;
  }
}
</script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('option1').addEventListener('change', function () {
        document.getElementById('option2').selectedIndex = this.selectedIndex;
    });
</script>
```

An event is added to option1 through the addEventListener() method that will be executed when the user selects any option in that 'select', this event allows to change the option selected in option2, assigning to the property selectedIndex (indicates the selected index) the index of the option selected in option1. As a result, if the first option is selected in option1 is selected the first option of option2 and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.